# Show that the series $\sum\limits_{n\ge1}a_nX_n$ converges absolutely a.s. for some constants $a_n\ne0$.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

> Let$\{X_n\}_{n\ge1}$ be an arbitrary sequence of random variables. Show that the series $\sum\limits_{n\ge1}a_nX_n$ converges absolutely a.s. for some constants $a_n\ne0$.

My attempt at a solution:

For any $n$ there exists a $b_n\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $P\big(\big|\frac{X_n}{b_n}\big|>\frac{1}{2^n}\big)<\frac{1}{2^n}$
\begin{align*}
&\implies \sum_{n\ge1}P\bigg(\bigg|\frac{X_n}{b_n}\bigg|>\frac{1}{2^n}\bigg)\le\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{2^n}<\infty\\
&\implies P\bigg(\bigg|\frac{X_n}{b_n}\bigg|>\frac{1}{2^n}\quad\text{i.o.}\bigg)=0\\
&\implies P\bigg(\bigg|\frac{X_n}{b_n}\bigg|\le\frac{1}{2^n}\quad\text{eventually}\bigg)=1\\
&\implies\exists\,\,N\in\mathbb{N}\,\,\text{such that}\,\,\bigg|\frac{X_n}{b_n}\bigg|\le\frac{1}{2^n}\,\,\text{a.s. for all}\,\,n\ge N\\
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\ge1}\bigg|\frac{X_n}{b_n}\bigg|<\infty&\iff\sum_{n\ge N}\bigg|\frac{X_n}{b_n}\bigg|<\infty\\
&\iff\sum_{n\ge N}\frac{1}{2^n}<\infty,\,\,\text{which is true.}
\end{align*}
And so the result is shown with $a_n=\frac{1}{b_n}$

Does this solution work? Also, is there a simpler or more elegant way to show this?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a condition that prevents you taking $a_n = 0$ for all $n$?

Comment: @RobArthan Yeah, thats a great point, its not explicitly written in the problem statement but I'm sure it is to be assumed. I'll edit the question and put that condition in there.

Comment: You need to justify your claim of the existence of the $b_n$. The rest of your argment looks good.

Comment: @RobArthan Ok awesome, thanks!